# jcombobox popup not painted correctly

Tags: java, swing, search, jcombobox

I have two questions 
1- I'm using a `JTextField` to search in my database and populate the result to a `JComboBox` 
the problem is when I use popup for combobox a part of its height is visually disappeared or not completely painted and also a part of the `JScrollPane` so how to referesh the look and feel to view the complete combobox while using show popup or setpopupvisible to true

2- The second question is about how to use the `JComboBox` as a search box , means how to get the input from it like using getText() from `JTextField` ?

Comment: For the first question, try to call the `repaint()`method of `JComboBox` just after setting popup visible. What do you mean by the second question? Do you mean `getSelectedItem()`?

Comment: 1)What do you mean popup in context of `JComboBox`?2) show how your pop up looks when it isn't painted correctly.3) Do you add `JCombobox` to `JScrollPane`? 

For second question I recommend you to search autocomplete combobox, here is a lot of examples.

Comment: Second quesion - `setEditable(true);`, add an `ActionListener`

Comment: @MounirHamoudi thanks for replying but the repaint and revalidate does not solve the problem , I have solved it by setting popup to false then set it to true mean use it two times at the same place like this 
box.setpopupvisible(false);
box.setpopupvisible(true);


for the second question I have solved it also by using box.geteditor().getitem();

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by setting popup to false then set it to true mean use it two times at the same place like this box.setpopupvisible(false);
box.setpopupvisible(true);

for the second question I have solved it also by using 
box.geteditor().getitem();